# Change the way how list is serialized into XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

So, I have a class with a list of objects like this:

```
public int SourceId { get; set; }
public int TargetId { get; set; }
public List<ExtraParameter> ExtraParameters { get; }
```

Then, when it is serialized into XML file, the output is like this:

```
<Connection>
    <SourceId>0</SourceId>
    <TargetId>1</TargetId>
    <ExtraParameters>
      <ExtraParameter>
        <Input>0</Input>
        <Output>1</Output>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      </ExtraParameter>
      <ExtraParameter>
        <Input>1</Input>
        <Output>0</Output>
        <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      </ExtraParameter>
     </ExtraParameters>
</Connection>
```

But I need to serialize this array of elements (ExtraParameter) using C#'s XmlSerializer into this form:

```
<Connection>
   <SourceId>0</SourceId>
   <TargetId>1</TargetId>
   <ExtraParameter>
      <Input>0</Input>
      <Output>1</Output>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
   </ExtraParameter>
   <ExtraParameter>
      <Input>1</Input>
      <Output>0</Output>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
   </ExtraParameter>
</Connection>
```

So in other words, can I somehow just list the items in that ExtraParameters-list without having that list in this hierarchy? So it does look like objects in the ExtraParameters are just listed at the end of the TargetID-node.

edit: Yes, I know, this kinda breaks the structure, but this xml file is then deserialized by the next program correctly, and I don't have control over that.

Comment: Hi! This is the way how the next system will deserialize this xml file correctly, and I don't have control over it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding the `XmlElement` attribute to the relevant property. Per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute?view=net-6.0):

> If you apply the `XmlElementAttribute` to a field or property that returns an array, the items in the array are encoded as a sequence of XML elements.

```cs
[XmlElement("ExtraParameter")]
public List<ExtraParameter> ExtraParameters { get; }
```

You could also change the property name rather than adding a value for `ElementName` to the attribute.

See [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dfyqfD) for a working demo.